# Find next occurence of weekday X in month Y and/or/without month day Z

Tags: php, date, time, cron

Essentially, what I need is the ability to tell what week day is coming next by the user selected week day, month & month day. It's for a cron job (I'm using both standard and page loading cron jobs for my portable application. They'll both be ran the same way (apart from so in the admin panel the user will have the ability to see the next scheduled run of task X)

Everything is working perfectly so far without the week day. But I have no idea how to implement this. I need a system where the user will select, say, the month 'January', the week day 'Saturday' and month day '13', even if it's two, three .etc years in the future. Or even just the first two of those. From this, I need to set the next scheduled run of the task. There are still a few undefined variables .etc, but I'm in the process of tidying it up a bit.

Here is what I have so far:

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks l like you have a numeric value for month, year, and day. You are using mktime (actually gmmktime, but it is mktime). You can add 7 to the day to get the next week. Abbreviated: mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day+7, $year); That will automatically return the timestamp for 7 days after the date you have.

Comment: "[W]hat I need is the ability to tell what week day is coming next by the user selected week day." So if the user selects Friday, the result will be Saturday? Not quite clear what you are asking.

Comment: @BenjaminHubbard - Sorry if I was unclear. I meant if the user selects Friday, I'd need the next Friday suitable to the criteria specified.

Comment: So based on the example in your second paragraph, the next Saturday after January 13?

Comment: Based on that example it would be every Saturday in January which has the day of 13 (basically every 13th of Saturday in January whenever that next is, 2,3, 4years time .etc)

Another example could be every Monday in June, that's easier than the first. It's purely down to the day, month and week day specified whether they're all, or specific.

But it has to be the next one.